# Grid Layout using CardView is not Showing on some old Android devices

Tags: android

I creating a home GridView layout with cardviews, the problem is, the cardview doesn't show on some old devices for example API 22.

**I am using**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

**Here is my code:**

```
            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#EC407A"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_service" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/aboutusButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ABOUT"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: did you try this ? implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: Yes I have mentioned above please look